# tesseract _BLOCK_TYPE_IS_VALID

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2013, tesseract

I'm a total beginner to tesseract OCR.
I'm trying to extract text alongwith the Bounding Boxes from images. I'm using the ResultIterator example from https://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/wiki/APIExample#Compiling_C++_API_programs_on_Linux
but am continuously getting the runtime error : _BLOCK_TYPE_IS_VALID (pHead -> nBlockUse).
Please guide how can i resolve this.
I'm compiling on VS2013, Tesseract v3.02

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll take a shot at it: did you, by any chance, compiled the libraries following the steps [here](http://vorba.ch/2014/tesseract-3.03-vs2013.html) ? If so, after compiling, you may have told your linker to input libtesseract304.lib, which is the library compiled for the Release version, while you are on Debug. And you also probably commented the `delete[] text` to get rid of the error, but there was an tiny itch at the back of your brain telling you it wasn't right.

If all of the above is true, then you might want to input libtesseract304d.lib (and the same for leptopnica). Notice the "d" at the end, it's for "debug". These kind of issues happen when there is a difference like 32bit vs 64bit, Debug vs Release and all the others that may be.